# Why is the computation faster with a loop?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, time

**Update:**

As pointed out by @Dave2e, moving the `start_time` statement (in code 2) out of the `for` loop will make the running time comparable to code 1. Namely:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (j in 1:1) {
   n <- 100
   result <- 1
   for (i in 1:n) {
     result <- result * i
   }
   result
   ## [1] 9.332622e+157
   end_time <- Sys.time()
}
end_time - start_time
```

Does the `for` loop really improve the performance or is it fake?

---

Original Post:

I have two pieces of code as follows:

#### Code 1:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
n <- 100
result <- 1
for (i in 1:n) {
   result <- result * i
}
result
## [1] 9.332622e+157
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

#### Code 2:

```
for (j in 1:1) {
   start_time <- Sys.time()
   n <- 100
   result <- 1
   for (i in 1:n){
      result <- result * i}
      result
      ## [1] 9.332622e+157
      end_time <- Sys.time()
   }
   end_time - start_time
```

I was expecting these two codes run similarly, but code 2 constantly runs significantly faster than code 1. On my computer, code 1 takes about 10^-2 seconds, while code 2 takes about 5*10^-6 seconds. Any insight on how this could happen? If just adding `for` loop to the entire codes can decrease program running time, I will use it on all my codes in the future.

Comment: In code 2 move the `start_time` statement to outside the "for" loop and then the times are comparable.  The `for` statement must send a signal to pre-evalute the loop prior to actually executing it. Someone with a deeper knowledge of the R may provide a better answer.

Comment: *"Does the for loop really improve the performance or is it fake?"* It makes it worse! And it's understandable, since you are running something extra.

Comment: Before doing this, I thought exactly the same as you. But the running time in the above examples made me confused, and I don't know if R is implemented in a way that using a loop changes the way it runs which saves time on certain computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your comparison is very robust.  It's very hard to tell anything about the relative timing of very fast code without running it many times to get an average - too many uncontrollable factors can change the running time slightly.

The conclusion I would draw from the benchmarks below is that **encapsulating a fairly trivial computation in a redundant for loop doesn't hurt very much**, but that any apparent advantage is trivial and probably just an effect of noise.

I encapsulated each of your code chunks in a function (`with_loop` and `without_loop`) by putting `function() { ... }` around each of them. (Note that this means I'm not basing the timings on your `Sys.time()` comparisons, but on the built-in timing in the `microbenchmark` package.)

The `microbenchmark` package is more suitable for benchmarking, especially for very short computational tasks: from `?microbenchmark::microbenchmark`:

> ‘microbenchmark’ serves as a more accurate replacement of the
>        often seen ‘system.time(replicate(1000, expr))’ expression. It
>        tries hard to accurately measure only the time it takes to
>        evaluate ‘expr’. To achieved this, the sub-millisecond (supposedly
>        nanosecond) accurate timing functions most modern operating
>        systems provide are used. Additionally all evaluations of the
>        expressions are done in C code to minimize any overhead.

```
library(microbenchmark)
m1 <- microbenchmark(with_loop, without_loop)
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(m1)+scale_y_log10()
```

The quantiles (lq, median, uq) are practically identical.

```
Unit: nanoseconds
         expr min lq   mean median uq   max neval cld
    with_loop  36 38  48.56     39 40   972   100   a
 without_loop  36 39 177.81     40 41 13363   100   a
```

[image]

The code without the loop is indeed slower *on average* (i.e. it has a larger mean), but this is almost entirely driven by a couple of outliers.

Now focus just on values less than 50 nanoseconds:

```
autoplot(m1)+scale_y_log10(limits=c(NA,50))
```

[image]

If we do this again with `times=1e6` (a million iterations), we get almost identical results: the mean with the loop is 3 **nanoseconds** faster (again probably almost entirely driven by small fluctuations in the upper tail).

```
Unit: nanoseconds
         expr min lq     mean median uq     max neval cld
    with_loop  32 39 86.44248     41 61 2474675 1e+06   a
 without_loop  35 39 89.86294     41 61 2915836 1e+06   a
```

If you need to run your loop a billion times, this will correspond to a 3-second difference in run time. Probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Your simulation results are very helpful. Based on those, I think it's safe to conclude that using a 'for' loop to include the entire code does not hurt the computation time, instead, it improves it sometime. It will be more interesting if you can post the standard deviation of the running time in your second simulation. I wonder that 3 nanoseconds is significant or not.

Comment: In my research, I frequently have to run a simulation for 1e6 iterations, which very likely will encounter noises. If I only run it with one or two iterations, I won't care about these differences. Logically, I never thought about adding a non-sense loop could possibly change anything until I accidentally found the posted situation. I am not familiar with the design of R, but I will consider using 'for' loop to include everything as an option to compare computation time in my future research before submitting the job to cluster.

Comment: For a million iterations, a mean of  3 nano-seconds difference per iteration would correspond to a difference of 0.001 seconds for the entire run. In my opinion you'd be wasting time to worry about this difference.

Comment: Do you have any idea why using microbenchmark and Sys.time give such a different result?

Comment: Some combination of the fancy stuff that microbenchmark does (see edits) and **the fact that a single evaluation is typically very noisy**.   Are these comparisons based on your "original" or on your "adjusted" code? 0.01 seconds could easily just be the time that it takes for your computer to switch states and move R to the top of the queue